# Query for documents that have dependent elements in another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
Collection1
  name
  slug
Collection2
  name
  slugCollection1
```

The "link" between `Collection1` and `Collection2` is through fields `slug` and `slugCollection1`.

I want to create a query that returns elements from `Collection1` with a new computed boolean attribute that tells if there are (or not) dependent elements in `Collection2`.

For this, I created the following query:

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "localField": "slug",
      "foreignField": "slugCollection1",
      "as": "elements"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "id": "$id",
      "name": 1,
      "slug": 1,
      "hasElements": {
        $gt: [ { $size: '$elements' }, 0 ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have performance issues on this when there are a lot of elements in both collections and even the following error:

```
MongoError: Total size of documents in collection2 matching { slug: { $eq: "paymill" } } exceeds maximum document size
```

Is there another way to implement such a request? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need all the fields in `collection1`? You can also set [`allowDiskUse`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) to `true` to write to temp files

Comment: What do you mean by all the fields? I don't need all the "joined" fields from collection2, actually only one to be able to use then `$size`. Is it possible to specify the fields to include at the level of `$lookup`. Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is that if you don't need to all the document's field in "collection1" then you can first project them and discard those fields. But you can do the same for "collection2". Also try to use the `allowDiskUse` to see if it will help. If that doesn't work you will probably need to change your documents structure or use two different queries to get the final result.

Comment: The way to get around this is to actually include an `$unwind` right after `$lookup`, and preferably followed by `$match`. Sounds counter-intuitive I know, but MongoDB actually "hoists" the `$unwind` and `$match` "into" the `$lookup` operation. This stops the BSON limit being broken. Unfortunately only the server processes this syntax and you cannot as yet write the equivalent statement directly yourself. It's arcane things like this which make me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a $project stage before $lookup so you can use only required field to lookup

```
      {
        "$project": {
          "name": 1,
          "slug": 1
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! In fact, I think that the problem is because of the fields in collection2. Instead of a "$lookup", I would like to have a "count" of corresponding rows in "collection2" or a "$lookup" on a subset of fields from collection2 (in my case, `_id` is enough). Is it something possible?

Comment: No you cant do that in $lookup,The field which are using for joining are string it takes time to join.Add an index on both collection field(slug,slugCollection1)